# Java - Alternatives to forcing subclass to have a static method

Tags: java

I often find I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo{
public static abstract String getParam();
}
```

To force a subclasses of Foo to return a parameter.

I know you can't do it and I know why you can't do it but the common alternative of:

```
class Foo{
public abstract String getParam();
}
```

Is unsatisfactory because it requires you to have an instance which is not helpful if you just want to know the value of the parameter and instantiating the class is expensive.

I'd be very interested to know of how people get around this without getting into using the "Constant Interface" anti pattern.

EDIT: I'll add some more detail about my specific problem, but this is just the current time when I've wanted to do something like this there are several others from the past.

My subclasses are all data processors and the superclass defines the common code between them which allows them to get the data, parse it and put it where it needs to go. 
The processors each require certain parameters which are held in an SQL database. Each processor should be able to provide a list of parameters that it requires and the default values so the configuration database can be validated or initialised to defaults by checking the required parameters for each processor type. 
Having it performed in the constructor of the processor is not acceptable because it only needs to be done once per class not once per object instance and should be done at system startup when an instance of each type of class may not yet be needed.

Comment: If you're already calling `Class.getName()`, why do you need to get the name anyway?

Comment: It's an example. I could say get gigawidgets

Comment: interesting question.  Do you have a concrete example handy?  It might help stir up some ideas. Scala has a nice way of handling this - it's the difference between an object and a class - that probably won't help you much tho.

Comment: @jeff I've added some more detail. to the question. I think I could easily do what I want in Scala, or Python, or C# so it's surprising their doesn't seem to be a java equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

The best you can do here in a static context is something like one of the following:

a.  Have a method you specifically look for, but is not part of any contract (and therefore you can't enforce anyone to implement) and look for that at runtime:

```
 public static String getParam() { ... };
 try {
     Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getParam");
     String param = (String) m.invoke(null);
 }
 catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
   // handle this error
 }
```

b.  Use an annotation, which suffers from the same issue in that you can't force people to put it on their classes.

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Param {
   String value() default "";
}

@Param("foo")
public class MyClass { ... }


public static String getParam(Class<?> clazz) {
   if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Param.class)) {
      return clazz.getAnnotation(Param.class).value();
   }
   else {
      // what to do if there is no annotation
   }
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the annotation.

Answer (score 8):

I agree - I feel that this is a limitation of Java.  Sure, they have made their case about the advantages of not allowing inherited static methods, so I get it, but the fact is I have run into cases where this would be useful.  Consider this case:

I have a parent `Condition` class, and for each of its sub-classes, I want a `getName()` method that states the class' name.  The name of the sub-class will not be the Java's class name, but will be some lower-case text string used for JSON purposes on a web front end.  The `getName()` method will not change per instance, so it is safe to make it static.  However, some of the sub-classes of the `Condition` class will not be allowed to have no-argument constructors - some of them I will need to require that some parameters are defined at instantiation.

I use the `Reflections` library to get all classes in a package at runtime.  Now, I want a list of all the names of each `Condition` class that is in this package, so I can return it to a web front end for JavaScript parsing.  I would go through the effort of just instantiating each class, but as I said, they do not all have no-argument constructors.  I have designed the constructors of the sub-classes to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if some of the parameters are not correctly defined, so I cannot merely pass in null arguments.  This is why I want the `getName()` method to be static, but required for all sub-classes.

My current workaround is to do the following:  In the `Condition` class (which is abstract), I have defined a method:

```
public String getName () {
    throw new IllegalArugmentException ("Child class did not declare an overridden getName() method using a static getConditionName() method.  This must be done in order for the class to be registerred with Condition.getAllConditions()");
}
```

So in each sub-class, I simply define:

```
@Override
public String getName () {
    return getConditionName ();
}
```

And then I define a static `getConditionName()` method for each.  This is not quite "forcing" each sub-class to do so, but I do it in a way where if getName() is ever inadvertently called, the programmer is instructed how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you want to solve the wrong problem with the wrong tool. *If* all subclasses *define* (can't really say inherit) your static method, you will still be unable to call it painlessly (To call the static method on a class not known at compile time would be via reflection or byte code manipulation).

And if the idea is to have a set of behaviors, why not just use instances that all implement the same interface? An instance with no specific state is cheap in terms of memory and construction time, and if there is no state you can always share one instance (flyweight pattern) for all callers.

If you just need to couple metadata with classes, you can build/use any metadata facility you like, the most basic (by hand) implementation is to use a Map where the class object is the key. If that suits your problem depends on your problem, which you don't really describe in detail.

EDIT: (Structural) Metadata would associate data with *classes* (thats only one flavor, but probably the more common one). Annotations can be used as very simple metadata facility (annotate the class with a parameter). There are countless other ways (and goals to achieve) to do it, on the complex side are frameworks that provide basically every bit of information designed into an UML model for access at runtime.

But what you describe (processors and parameters in database) is what I christened "set of behaviors". And the argument "parameters need to be loaded once *per class*" is moot, it completely ignores the idioms that can be used to solve this without needing anything 'static'. Namely, the flyweight pattern (for having only once instance) and lazy initialization (for doing work only once). Combine with factory as needed.

Comment: Could you describe your final paragraph in more detail. I have added more detail to the question. I want to avoid having the metadata held centrally,

Comment: @NickLong You seem to be firmly set on the 'static' approach. You need to adjust your set of mind. Having an instance of a class opens up all the advantages of inheritance and polymorphism. Shed the thought that such a funtcion holder instance is wasted - those ~16 bytes per instance will not make your application a memory eating behemoth.

Comment: Your example of data processors + parameters *calls* for a dataprocessor *factory* that spews out initialized instances. Also mind you, *static* is *worse* than keeping anything *centrally* (the latter could at least be altered at runtime, when the need arises). Static means automatically *compile time dependency* (to avoid that you *have* to go dynamic, at least part of the way. Might as well go all the way then).

Comment: It doesn't need to be altered at run time. It is the list of parameters that the processors use not the value of these parameters so I want it defined at compile time. Putting in a central repository would seem to be bad encapsulation and would require developers to alter things in two places in sync.

Comment: Just because something doesn't need to be altered is a bad case of justifing a strictly unalterable approach. If you just create a RequiredParameters class to describe the parameters, each *instance* of processor can create its description and expose it through the base class/interface (a simple approach would be have the base class required the parameters as constructor argument). Where do you see a second place to keep in sync? Naturally you have to alter you processor factory (or its configuration file) to make a processor *known* to the system. What would static code simplify there?

Comment: Requiring the parameters in the constructor is functionally equivalent to an abstract getter in the superclass. It still doesn't help you access the parameters in a static way. I should add that I'm working on an existing codebase so I'm not at liberty to change fundamental things

Comment: Well of course it is. I'm trying to convince you that the static approach is the wrong tool here :) If you *need* a static approach (I can't but wonder how you pass around your static processor now?), then you could abuse annotations (if the parameter definitons can be expressed in primitives/Strings) or if you really want, use reflection to call the static method. Simply *throw* if the class does not define the required method(s). I don't think there is any way to get a compile time error for this.

Comment: I like your answer, but I want to respond to your suggestion to use instances.  I often find cases where it's not convenient to create an instance when you need to make a class-dependent query.  For instance, the class may be an abstract parent of a hierarchy (pick one subclass and instantiate?) or there may be a number of parameters, irrelevant to the query, required to make a concrete instance.  In those cases, it's like making a testing mock in order to provide the query.  I agree  one just has to work around it and like the suggestions here, but I think the *desire* is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem over and over again and it's hard for me to understand why Java 8 preferred to implement lambda instead of that.

Anyway, if your subclasses only implement retrieving a few parameters and doing rather simple tasks, you can use [enumerations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) as they are very powerful in Java: you can basically consider it a fixed set of instances of an interface. They can have members, methods, etc. They just can't be instanciated (as they are "pre-instanciated").

```
public enum Processor {
    PROC_IMAGE {
        @Override
        public String getParam() {
            return "image";
        }
    },

    PROC_TEXT {
        @Override
        public String getParam() {
            return "text";
        }
    }
    ;

    public abstract String getParam();

    public boolean doProcessing() {
        System.out.println(getParam());
    }
}
```

The nice thing is that you can get all "instances" by calling `Processor.values()`:

```
for (Processor p : Processorvalues()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Param %s: %s", p.name(), p.getParam()));
    p.doProcessing();
}
```

If the processing is more complex, you can do it in other classes that are instanciated in the enum methods:

```
@Override
public String getParam() {
    return new LookForParam("text").getParam();
}
```

You can then enrich the enumeration with any new processor you can think of.

The down side is that you can't use it if other people want to create new processors, as it means modifying the source file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **factory pattern** to allow the system to create 'data' instances first, and create 'functional' instances later. The 'data' instances will contain the 'mandatory' getters that you wanted to have `static`. The 'functional' instances do complex parameter validation and/or expensive construction. Of course the parameter setter in the factory can also so preliminary validation.

```
public abstract class Processor { /*...*/ }

public interface ProcessorFactory {
    String getName(); // The  mandatory getter in this example

    void setParameter(String parameter, String value);

    /** @throws IllegalStateException when parameter validation fails */
    Processor construct();
}

public class ProcessorA implements ProcessorFactory {
    @Override
    public String getName() { return "processor-a"; }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(String parameter, String value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(parameter, "parameter");
        Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value");
        switch (parameter) {
            case "source": setSource(value); break;
            /*...*/
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameter: " + parameter);
        }
    }

    private void setSource(String value) { /*...*/ }

    @Override
    public Processor construct() {
        return new ProcessorAImpl();
    }

    // Doesn't have to be an inner class. It's up to you.
    private class ProcessorAImpl extends Processor { /*...*/ }
}
```